# WPF Binding on Entity Framework

Tags: wpf, data-binding, frameworks, entity

I have MS SQL Server database with one table - Peoples. From these database generated Entity Framework Data model.
In WPF application I have ListBox with ItemSource = DataModel.Entities.Peoples, and two buttons - add and remove People in database.
Add button:

```
DataModel.Entities.AddPeople(new People("test"));
DataModel.Entities.SaveChanges();
```

And removing:

```
DataModel.Entities.Remove((People)listBox1.SelectedItem);
DataModel.Entities.SaveChanges();
```

When I click remove button - corresponding People row removing from databases and listBox1 refreshing. But when I click add button - People added in database (see in MS SQL Enterprise Manager), but listbox does not refreshing.

How to refresh listBox on adding? Guess I forgot to set any option in DataModel?

Comment: What is your XAML binding to?

Comment: listBox1.ItemSource = DataModel.Entities.Peoples;

Comment: There is no XAML binding. In listbox uses overriden People.ToString() and all work correct

Answer (score 2):

Unless `DataModel.Entities.Peoples` is an **`ObservableCollection`**, it won't be aware of changes.

I recommend you use the MVVM pattern for this, which solves that problem perfectly.

Comment: No, it's not observable collection, but maybe inherits from ObservableCollection<>. But why listbox refreshes after deleting element and not refreshing after inserting.

Comment: That's a good point I bet Entity Framework doesn't automatically refresh on Add (but has to on remove so it doesn't cause weird errors). Try telling it to Refresh your Peoples and see if it solves it for you.